# Simple SQL query..cannot get it resolved

Tags: sql, join

I have simple app where are two tables: Enemies and Weapon. Every Weapon must belong to some Enemy. Therefore Weapon has a column ReferenceID that references EnenyID.
I can easily check how many enemies do have a weapon:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Weapons JOIN Enemies ON Weapons.RefID=Enemies.ID
```

But how can I find out vice versa how many enemies do not have any weapon associated? I.e., how many Enemies here are whose ReferenceID is not used by any Weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Enemies
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Weapons WHERE Weapons.RedID=Enemies.ID)
```

Comment: how do we call this technique in sql query?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM Enemies 
LEFT JOIN Weapons ON Weapons.RefID = Enemies.ID 
WHERE Enemies.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT * FROM Enemies LEFT JOIN Weapons ON Weapons.RefID=Enemies.ID HAVING count(weapons.id) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select count(*) from Enemies where Enemies.ID not in (Select RefId From Weapons)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(*)
From enemies
Where id not in (select referenceid from weapons)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(*) 
From Weapons 
WHERE Not Exists (Select * From Enemies Where Weapons.RefID = Enemies.ID)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Enemies that do not have a weapon associated can be accomplished by:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Enemies
LEFT JOIN Weapons ON Enemies.ID = Weapons.RefID
WHERE   Weapons.ID IS NULL
```

It might be of note that your original query might not give you what you want in that if two weapons are associated to a single enemy you might get duplicates when counting, another possibility for your original query might be:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Enemies.ID
FROM    Weapons 
JOIN    Enemies ON Weapons.RefID=Enemies.ID
```